# defaultChannel.send is not a function

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have some code to greet the server when the bot is added.

```
client.on("guildCreate", guild => {
    const defaultChannel = guild.channels.find(c => c.permissionsFor(guild.me).has("SEND_MESSAGES"));
    defaultChannel.send(`Hi! Thanks for adding me to your server!`).catch(console.error);
});
```

It finds a channel where it can send messages to and sends a thanking message.

When I run the above code I get the follwing error: `TypeError: defaultChannel.send is not a function`

Comment: `client.guild.channels` what guild?

Comment: The guild that the bot has joined... I don't understand your question...

Comment: Does it actually manage to find the channel? `find` returns `undefined` if it cannot find what it's looking for, and it looks like that's the case here. When you call `send` on `undefined` you get that error.

Comment: i tried using `client.channels.get` and i get this: "Cannot read property 'send' of undefined", so it seems like it cant find the channel. could anyone help with that?

Comment: I'd try logging both `guild.channels` and `defaultChannel` to have a closer look at what's going on behind the scenes. If the collection `guild.channels` has a channel in which the bot has permissions to send messages, but `defaultChannel` remains undefined, then perhaps something is wrong with your `.find()` callback function.